CAPL DLL File Invalid Error When Starting Simulation in CANoe
I attempted to build a CAPL DLL file for CANoe following the CMake example provided in the Vector Help documentation. Additionally, I used similar steps from this githup repository: huangdong332/bootloader.
I successfully created the CAPL DLL and imported it into the CAPL browser using #pragma library. The compilation succeeded, and I could import and see the functions from the DLL in the CAPL code.
However, when I try to start the simulation, I encounter the following error:
** requested capl dll is invalid **

This error disappears only when I comment out the functions I am using from the DLL file.
I attempted to change the compiler architecture from 32-bit to 64-bit (located at C:/msys64/mingw64/bin), but it didn't resolve the issue.
I haven't tried using any generator other than MSYS. Here are the commands I'm using:
mkdir build-msys
cd build-msys
cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ..
C:\msys64\usr\bin\make.exe
I'm using 64-bit CANoe config.
I'm compiling for 32-bit and i didnt try on another device
This is my Cmakelists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(CaplDllExample VERSION 0.0) 
# Specify the MSYS2 32-bit compilers
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe")

# Add the source files
add_library(dl2 SHARED ../Sources/dl2.cpp)
if (WIN32)
  set_target_properties(dl2 PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
else()
  target_compile_options(dl2 PUBLIC "-fvisibility=hidden")
endif() 

What could be causing the "requested capl dll is invalid" error when starting the simulation in CANoe, and how can I resolve it?

Are you using a 32-bit or 64-bit CANoe config? Are you compiling your Dll in 32-bit or 64-bit? How does your CMakelists.txt file look like? Do you try to execute with runtimekernel running on a separate device (VN89xx)?

im using 64-bit CANoe config , im compiling for 32-bit and
i didnt try on another device.
this is my Cmakelists.txt -->
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(CaplDllExample VERSION 0.0)
Specify the MSYS2 32-bit compilers
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/gcc.exe")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "C:/msys64/mingw32/bin/g++.exe")
Add the source files
add_library(dl2 SHARED ../Sources/dl2.cpp)
if (WIN32)
set_target_properties(dl2 PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
else()
target_compile_options(dl2 PUBLIC "-fvisibility=hidden")
endif()

im using 64-bit CANoe config , im compiling for 32-bit Well, that should be the problem.  When the config is 64-bit, that means the RuntimeKernel (the process executing your CAPL code) is a 64 bit process, which does not understand 32-bit dlls. What happens, when you add -m64 to the compile options?

Could you please guide me on how to add the -m64 compiler option and where exactly to add it? I'm not fully aware of the steps to do this.

Change the second-to-last line in your CMakeLists.txt to target_compile_options(dl2 PUBLIC "-fvisibility=hidden" "-m64") (and of course, use the 64-bit compiler exe)

I tried using the -m64 option, but it results in the same error mentioned in my original question. Additionally, switching the compiler from mingw32 to mingw64 leads to a warning: "Could not open (dll path)".

We need much more information: when is the warning "Could not open ..." thrown? During compilation, during linking, when editing in CAPL browser, when starting the measurement, ...?
Is the compilation with 64-bit successful? Is the DLL placed in the same location as the 32-bit DLL?
Please add all information to the question.

target_compile_options(dl2 PUBLIC "-fvisibility=hidden" "-m64")
in this line changing "-m64" to "-m32" fixed the problem
